# Output reflow in ansi-term

Tags: ansi-term, wrapping

In `gnome-terminal`, the output of some commands is automatically "reflowed", in the sense that if the file `tmp` has content `0000000000` and the terminal has width `9`, the output will be displayed as

```
$ cat tmp
000000000
0
```

but after resizing the terminal to more than `9` columns, the output of the above command (without running it again) will be displayed as

```
$ cat tmp
0000000000
```

In Emacs, doing the same test with `ansi-term` will leave the output unchanged after resizing the terminal buffer.

Is there any way that the buffer "saves" the output as a full line without cutting it first? The display of the full line would then be handled like a normal text buffer, supporting resizing and wrapping.

Comment: As seen in the linked answer, this was solved with `(setq term-suppress-hard-newline t)`, thank you for linking.